# Java passing Array to generic method

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have this generic method:

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> type, String... keys)
{
    String key = String.join(".", keys);
    if(this._data.containsKey(key))
        return type.cast(this._data.get(key));

    return null;
}
```

and I need to pass a generic Array as type but I don't understand how to do it:

```
public <T extends SearchableItem> ArrayList<T> filterAudio(T[] type, int taxonomyId, TaxonomyLevel level, int count) {
    T[] all = (T[])masterDbManager.get(type, "audiotracks-alphabetic");
    ....
}
```

But that doesn't work because the get() method wants a class:

> Error:(200, 39) java: method get in class com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.dal.MasterDbManager cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: java.lang.Class,java.lang.String[]
>     found: T[],java.lang.String
>     reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
>       (argument mismatch; T[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Class)

not an Array, so how can I use the get() method when I need to retrieve an Array?

Hope my request is clear :)

**EDIT**: ok I needed the .getClass() method

```
T[] all = (T[])masterDbManager.get(type.getClass(), dbKey);
```

**BUT** how do I now call the filterAudio() method from the following method?

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> searchAudio(Class<T> type, int taxonomyId, TaxonomyLevel taxonomyLevel, String searchText, int page, int pageSize, SearchOrder order) {
    ArrayList<T> all = filterAudio(???, taxonomyId, taxonomyLevel, 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: maybe try `type.getClass()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer You mean `getClass()`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer .class doesn't exist while getClass() did the trick, was that easy? I'm sure I already tried it but I probably I was just messing around. Thanks. Let me see if everything works correctly and if so you can post the aswer.

Comment: If that works, then it might be more suitable to delete this question.

Comment: Yes, let's make it SnapStackOverflow: destroy questions after the correct answer.

Comment: I've updated my question, please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case you can simply write `(T[])masterDbManager.get(Object.class, "audiotracks-alphabetic")` because you cast result to `T[]` anyway.

In general there is no `Class` corresponding to `T[]` type. It will by always `Array.class` no matter what base type array have.

Comment: Thanks, that should also answer to my last questions (I've edited my original question). Let me check it.

Comment: Answer for you last question is simple pass `(T[])null` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass exact type to get method. If your type is array then you will need to pass something like String[].class - according to the signature provided